# Concatenate string resources without losing HTML formatting

Tags: java, android, string-formatting

I need to put HTML-formatted text (simple stuff, with only a few `<b>/</b>` and `<i>/</i>` markers) into a TextView.
I need to combine three different lines of such text, each stored in a string resource like the following code.

```
(TextView) newText.setText(getString(R.string.textstr1) + getString(R.string.textstr2) + getString(R.string.textstr3));
```

It does not work because concatenating them as Strings drops the HTML formatting.

I tried solving it by using `getText()` instead of `getString()` and CharSequence.append(), but that also drops the HTML.  I tried various options using `HTML.fromHTML()`, but none of them worked either. Android Developer presents this crude approach where you have to use escaped HTML (< b > becomes & lt ; b > and so on), but that would require reformatting all of my string resources and strikes me as a kludge.

Does anyone know of a better way to do what I'm trying to do?

Comment: Duplicates of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8061796/how-do-i-concatenate-charsequences

Answer (score 3):

Method getString eliminates HTML tags, but there are two tricks available:

1. Use & lt; and & gt; instead of < and >. That would prevent getString from cutting tags out and still alow Html.fromHtml() to parse them.

Example:

```
<string name="text">This is &lt;i&gt;italic&lt;/i&gt;</string>
```

1. Use CDATA to wrap all string with HTML tags.

Example:

```
<string name="text"><![CDATA[This is <i>italic</i>]]></string>
```

In both cases all you have to do next is just setText.

```
yourTextView.setText(Html.fromHtml(getString(R.string.text)));
```

If you want some more examples check: 
http://android4beginners.com/2013/07/lesson-1-5-how-to-color-part-of-the-text-and-use-alpha-channel-in-textview/ (font color HTML tags in strings.xml)

Answer (score 0):

Try this, Hope it will help..

```
String newString=getString(R.string.textstr1) + getString(R.string.textstr2) + getString(R.string.textstr3);

newText.setText(Html.fromHtml(newString));
```

Comment: I tried this before; unfortunately, it works even worse as it not only eliminates the HTML font formatting but also the '\n' line breaks.

Answer (score 0):

```
(TextView) newText.setTextHtml.fromHtml((getString(R.string.textstr1) + getString(R.string.textstr2) + getString(R.string.textstr3)));
```

Comment: setTextHtml is not a method of TextView, so this only gets me an error message. Did you mean newText.setText(Html.fromHtml(... ?  That would make it the same as the previous suggestion.